# Read Revit Schedule data using design automation API

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I am planning to read schedule data from Revit files like (room schedule or door schedule).
is there an example doing so using design automation api for revit.

Answer (score 0):

We have some basic very basic samples that you can extend to achieve what you want. Any Revit API defined in the [Autodesk.Revit.DB](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/87546ba7-461b-c646-cbb1-2cb8f5bff8b2.htm) should work in Design Automation for Revit.

**[Code Samples](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/code_samples/code_samples/)** (look for CountDelete and SketchIt)

**[Postman Tutorials](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/about_tutorial/)**

**[Advanced Tutorials](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/)**

Comment: I went through the tutorial and create a Revit app. All worked fine. However I am facing an issue when trying uploading or updating the bundles more than 7 times. I receive an error : 403 error Maximum number of items exceeded. Typicaly i will need to upload/update more than 7 times untill i fully test bundle. Is there a way around it. PS: if i wait for some time (2 Hours) it lets upload.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, clearest and most comprehensive sample I have to offer on accessing schedule data is provided by the article on [The Schedule API and Access to Schedule Data](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/05/the-schedule-api-and-access-to-schedule-data.html).

Unfortunately, it predates DA4R, design automation for Revit.

Happily, you can easily adapt it by following the steps described in The Building Coder topic group on [DA4R – Design Automation for Revit](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.55).

Answer (score 0):

I used Rahul Link and made a very nice Schedule AddIn that work on BIM 360 Docs. 
One note i beleive you might face is when you get the " 403 error Maximum number of items exceeded" when uploading the bundle. the error was attributed to sending the file as a parameter. The resolution was reading the file into memory first then pass it as form-data.